# Noise, Vibration & Harshness resources

Tags: mechanical-engineering, acoustics

Would you have a recommendation to learn about NVH. I have a Materials Science and Engineering background. I am looking for learning about NVH in general.

I could find some resources about traditional vehicles such as [this](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/9789814713443_0011) that I could access, it is rather short (15 pages) but gives a first introduction to NVH. As well as this [book](https://www.sae.org/publications/books/content/r-481/) which seems good to me but I would like to avoid going for 100 bucks for getting to know this.

As a first approach, would you know good videos, documents or even MOOCs that cover this topic?

Many thanks in advance for your help.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

For NVH, Bruel and Kjaer have many free, and good, references in their website.

The Primer series is a good start, and the handbooks are essential in a vibration lab https://www.bksv.com/en/knowledge/library/primers-and-handbooks

The Frequency Analysis book contained enough details of Fourier etc to get me through a long career in NVH.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. It's why its been flagged as being a low quality answer.

Comment: I went on Bruel and Kjaer's website, and there are many different things that I cannot access. On top of that, I am a complete beginner in the field so I am not sure this really helps me to know which resources to look for there.

Comment: @KrKAlex, you hadn't mentioned you were a complete noob. Better questions get better answers.

Comment: @GregLocock "As a first approach, would you know good videos, documents or even MOOCs that cover this topic?" was pretty self-explanatory in my opinion. Sorry if it was not the case and that my question was not clear. Now, seeing how aggressive you are, I better avoid discussing further with you.

Comment: @KrKAlex good luck with your career.

Comment: Dear @GregLocock, I have a better understanding of NVH thanks to mostly the Frequency analysis and the Noise control documents in the link you forwarded. Thank you for sharing this resource. If you think of any other resources, more related to simulation and modeling, I would gladly welcome it. Thank you.